# iOS Image is too big for View Background, how to rescale?

Tags: ios, view, uiimage

I am trying to set the background of the `UIView`.
I set it properly, but the image I have is a lot bigger than the `UIView`, so only the top left of the `UIImage` gets displayed.

How can I re-scale it to fit the view properly?

Sample Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"signupbg.png"];
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: backgroundImage];
    backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.view insertSubview: backgroundImageView atIndex: 0];
    CGRect frame = backgroundImageView.frame;
    backgroundImageView.frame = frame;


    UIImageView* someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"navlogo.png"]];
    someImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = someImageView;

}
```

Comment: Fixed one problem but the title view problem still persists, any idea how to fix that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = backgroundImageView.frame;
backgroundImageView.frame = frame;
```

Above code does nothing. Use the following.

```
backgroundImageView.frame = [self.view bounds];
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem.  The same thing happens with the titleview, any idea to solve that one?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting clip to bounds :

```
[someImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you want to fill the view with the image

```
someImageView.contentMode =UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

tell me if this works or not